# Empty object returned in BeautifulSoup find_all method using a CSS selector

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, python-requests

I am using requests module in python to login into the results page. From there I want the program to print my name, marks etc on the terminal using bs4. While using 
`name = soupe.find_all("td", {"class": "celldata"})`  or
`names = soupe.find_all(class_="celldata")` the code works perfectly. But when i copy the CSS selector for my name i.e

```
namess = soupe.find_all(r'body > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(4) > td > div:nth-of-type(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(3)')
```

This returned an empty object. I think it should have returned my name. What is the problem with this way?
Also, can someone tell me when to use CSS selectors and when to do it manually.

Another problem that I faced was that in post method when I gave the URL of the website where I had to fill the form i.e

```
http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/kvpy-1415/checkMarks.php
```

then the program did not work. I had to change it to the URL of the page which contained student's name and rank etc. i.e

```
http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/kvpy-1415/checkMarksSuccess.php
```

which comes after filling the form.
why did this happen?

Here is the full code:

```
import requests
import bs4

s = requests.Session()

payload = {'id': '15015556', 'dd' : '25', 'mm' : '09', 'yyyy' : '1998'}

r = s.post(r'http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/kvpy-1415/checkMarksSuccess.php', payload)

if (r.text.find("Name of the Candidate")) >= 0:
    soupe = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    name = soupe.findAll("td", {"class": "celldata"})

    names = soupe.find_all(class_="celldata")

    namess = soupe.find_all(r'body > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(4) > td > div:nth-of-type(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(3)')
    print (namess)

    '''for n in name:
        print(n.get_text())'''
else:
    print("failure")
```

Comment: have you tried `select` instead of `find_all`? should work better for that long selector.